# Массив bool и statement C++

Tags: c++

По какой причине я попадаю в этот `if`?

```
bool* keys[256];
for(auto key : keys) { key = false; }
if (keys[GLFW_KEY_W]) // GLFW_KEY_W = 64
{
    std::cout << "I'm inside if" << std::endl;
    std::cout << keys[GLFW_KEY_W]; 
    position += front * velocity;
}
```

> I'm inside if
>
> 240

Как понять, что `keys[GLFW_KEY_W]` возвращает мне, как я понимаю индекс и при этом я еще и попадаю внутрь `if`? По какой причине я попадаю в него?

**UPD**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы попадаете в ошибку компиляции, выражение`bool* keys = keys[256];` не валидное. Даже если переписать `bool* keys[256];`, то обращение к любому элементу этого неинициализированного массива будет неопределенным поведением.

Comment: @VTT исправил. вопрос остался тот же

Comment: После правки у вас по-прежнему *"обращение к любому элементу этого неинициализированного массива будет неопределенным поведением"*, причем теперь оно происходит в строке `for(auto key : keys) { key = false; }` Если хотите инициализировать нулями, то достаточно сделать `bool* keys[256]{};`

Comment: `key = false;` дает `error: cannot convert 'bool' to 'bool*' in assignment`. *"токсичные школьники"* Вы для начала нормальный код в вопрос добавьте. (Минус не мой.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Обновил вопрос. У меня нету ошибок `error: cannot convert 'bool' to 'bool*' in assignment`

Comment: Что такое `GLFW_KEY_W` и чему оно равно? Почему вы инициализируете указатель значением `false`? Почему у вас объявлен массив из указателей `bool *`, хотя по сути нужен массив из обычных `bool`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш цикл

```
for(auto key : keys) { key = false; }
```

ничего не делает. Если вы хотите, чтобы `key = false;` модифицировало элементы массива, `key` должно быть ссылкой

```
for(auto &key : keys) { key = false; }
```

При этом начиная с С++11 литерал `false` больше не является допустимым вариантом null-pointer constant, т.е. `key = false` является некорректным кодом в любом случае.

Answer (score 2):

В цикле `for(auto key : keys)` переменная `key` - это **копия** очередного элемента массива.

`key = false;` меняет эту копию, а самого массива изменения не касаются.

Попробуйте `for(auto &key : keys)`.

---

Строго говоря, `key = false;` не должно компилироваться. Нет в С++ неявного преобразования из `bool` в указатели.

Правильнее написать `key = 0;` или `key = nullptr;`.

---

> `keys[GLFW_KEY_W]` возвращает мне, как я понимаю индекс

Это неинициализированный указатель.